# Can I use the RAM from my new MacBook Pro in my 4-year-old MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I just bought an i7 MBP with 4GB RAM. I'm upgrading it to 8GB with this: http://www.crucial.com/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=8C4DD5E1A5CA7304

So I'll have the brand-new 4GB RAM I'm removing. Can I put it in my old MBP? Here are the specs of the old one:

```
Model Identifier: MacBookPro2,2
Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo
Processor Speed: 2.16 GHz
Number Of Processors: 1
Total Number Of Cores: 2
L2 Cache: 4 MB
Memory: 3 GB
Bus Speed: 667 MHz


Memory:
Memory Slots:
ECC: Disabled
BANK 0/DIMM0:
  Size: 2 GB
  Type: DDR2 SDRAM
  Speed: 667 MHz
  Status: OK
BANK 1/DIMM1:
  Size: 1 GB
  Type: DDR2 SDRAM
  Speed: 667 MHz
  Status: OK
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. The largest DIMMs the 2.2 will take are 2GB ones, and it can't address more than 3GB, so it's already maxed out: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/apple/inside-the-macbook-pros-3gb-ram-limitation/321

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Mike Scott said (you're already at the maximum), the RAM from your new Mac is DDR3, while your old Mac uses DDR2, so the sticks probably won't even fit.